# Place div elements on responsive background (Bootstrap 3)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, background-image

I would like to place div's (input form) on a responsive background.

I'm using Bootstrap 3 for the page template. But if I resize the window or use another screen size the elements are on another place. How could I fix this common issue?

Example: http://goo.gl/D7TwIP
[image]
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using margin-top and margin-left use top and left properties on a positioned absolute element.

```
top: 540px;
left: 117px;
position: absolute;
```

Also make sure the parent element is set to position relative.

```
position: relative;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. And the size doesn't change to :(